# MySQL issue with altering column to add default

Tags: mysql, alter

I have a table named Users with a column call created. Whenever a record is created I want to add the datetime.

Users Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `userId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastName` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipCode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cellPhone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthDate` date NOT NULL,
  `creditCard` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `subscriptionStarted` date NOT NULL,
  `subscriptionEnded` date NOT NULL,
  `basicPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standardPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `premiumPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `systemAdmin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

now i added this extra query to make my created field get the current datetime when a new record is created.

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ALTER COLUMN created SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The problem is that I get the following error when running the alter table query

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off, I think you have to specify the column to change:

```
ALTER TABLE Users CHANGE created created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

See this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c02fe/1) for an example.

Comment: i get an error that says: Invalid default value for 'created'

Comment: @user3862830 I'm guessing you are maybe using a MySQL server version < 5.6; If so try changing the datetime to timestamp as earlier versions didn't initialize datetime fields.